# Finding the difference between a datetime object and current time (in seconds) in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Lets say I have a date-time object `2015-12-31T12:59`. Is there a way in PHP to find the difference between current date-time and the above date-time object in seconds? Basically, is there a way to find out the time in seconds from this very moment till the date-time specified by a future date-time object?

I did some digging and found out that there's a `DateTime` class in PHP, but I'm not sure whether it takes a format like `2015-12-31T12:59` as input.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you build a datetime object like `2015-12-31T12:59`, but you could simply `explode()` it on the T character and rebuild a normal DateTime string as input for the `DateTime` class.

Comment: @icecub I got the datetime object in the above format from the input type `datetime-local` in HTML.

Comment: I see. You do realise that `datetime-local` doesn't work in IE or Firefox right? It works fine in Chrome though. Still unless you're 100% sure that all of your users will be using Chrome (and you almost never are!), I wouldn't rely on this for a datetime object.

Comment: @icecub What input type would you recommend in my HTML forms to allow the users to select the date and time of their choice apart form the `datetime-local` input type?

Comment: I would use something like [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Have a calendar popup on input click event and disable the input. That way only the calendar can set its value. Ofcourse you could write something simular yourself. Just pointing it out as an example.

Comment: I should point out though that you should never ever rely on user input. Even if you disable the input, there are still ways to change the POST data before it's send to your server. Make sure to verify the input with regex in your backend so users can't mess with your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date() function to convert your date into the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch then you can substract the actual number of seconds since the Unix Epoch.

```
$myDate = date('2015-12-31T12:59'); //convert your date in seconds
$now = time(); //convert now in seconds
$numberOfSeconds = $myDate - $now; //make the difference
```

Note:
Unix Epoch = January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Dates on Unix systems can be stored in Epoch format (eg number of seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00).

The **time()** function does this naturally and other dates can be converted with something like **strtotime()**. All you have to do is subtract one from the other to get the time difference in seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this way this result will give the difference in sec,min,hr,days...

```
//use this way-----------------------

        $c_time=//your current time
        $date_current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $datetime1 = new DateTime($c_time);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($date_current_time);
        $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $f6=$difference->y.' Y '; 
        $f5=$difference->m.' M'; 
        $f4=$difference->d.' D';
        $f3=$difference->h.' hr';
        $f2=$difference->i.' min';
        $f1=$difference->s.' sec';

if($f2==0 && $f3==0 && $f4==0 && $f5==0 && $f6==0)
     {
         if($f1<=20)
           {
           $time=" few sec ago";
           }
         else if($f1>20)
           {
          $time=$f1." ago";
           }

     }
     else if($f3==0 && $f4==0 && $f5==0 && $f6==0)
     {
          if($f2<=2)
          {
          $time=" few min ago";
          }
         else if($f2>2)
          {
          $time=$f2." ago";
          }

     }
    else if($f4==0 && $f5==0 && $f6==0)
      {
         $time=$f3." ago";
      }
        else if($f5==0 && $f6==0)
      {

          $time=$f4." ago";
      }
        else if($f6==0)
      {
         $time=$f5." ago";
      }
    else
    {
    $time=$f6." ago";
    }
```

may this will help...to get the difference of time